# Safari z-index bug with video and 3D object

Tags: html, css, safari, 3d, html5-video

I want to make a sort of 3D room effect for my webpage. For this I created a 3D cube in css and it works fine in all browsers. My 3D cube has a black top-, and bottom side. Left, right and back side have a transparent background.

Here is my HTML setup:

```
<div class="room-container">
    <div class="video-background" id="room">
        <video class="bg-vid" autoplay preload="none" loop mute> 
            <source src="http://www.weichieprojects.com/demo-vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div><!-- ./video-background -->

    <div class="scroller">
        <div class="room">
            <div class="room-side room-side-top"></div>
            <div class="room-side room-side-back"></div>
            <div class="room-side room-side-left"></div>
            <div class="room-side room-side-right"></div>
            <div class="room-side room-side-bottom"></div>
        </div><!-- ./room -->
    </div><!-- ./scroller -->

    <div class="homepage-content text-center">
        <div class="inner">
            <h2>OPEN THIS PAGE IN SAFARI</h2>
            <h1>z-index buggy</h1>
            <h1>on safari and IE/Edge.</h1>
        </div><!-- ./inner -->
    </div><!-- ./homepage-content -->
</div><!-- ./room-container -->
```

If you check out my codepen (https://codepen.io/weichie/pen/GOVZQp) you will see the video background behind the cube. Unless you open the pen in Safari.

Anyone an idea on how I can fix the video background for Safari? Without the video, it works fine in Safari as well.

I have a div.room-container with an orange background and I gave the < video > a pink background. If you remove this line from my code:

```
<source src="http://www.weichieprojects.com/demo-vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

You'll see a pink background. (so the < video > is correctly placed behind my cube) If you remove the video-tag as well, you'll see the orange background behind the cube.

So it's super weird (I think) that only if there is a video involved, Safari places the video in front of my cube. However.. The text stays in front of the video. This is why I think it's a z-index issue on my 3D object?

Lots of thanks! [Here's an image on how my page should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikf37.jpg)